# Задать параллельный запуск подпроцесса Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, amazon-web-services, blender, render

Задача, сделать несколько рендеров параллельно. Из инструментов Python и Blender.

Есть скрипт, который запускает рендер Blender через консоль один за другим. Один рендер длиться приблизительно 1 минуту. Этот скрипт можно свести сейчас к двум строкам:

```
sh = ['blender', "-b", 'file.blend', "-P", 'script.py')]
proc = subprocess.run(sh)
```

Где script.py это файл где хранятся настройки сцены для одного рендера.

Так как рендеринг это довольно затратное дело, то я хочу запустить скрипт в отдельном процессе, по этому использую библиотеку multiprocessing. В итоге код стал выглядеть примерно так:

```
procs = []
for num in range(len(camera_points)):
    sh = ['blender', "-b", 'file.blend', "-P", f'script_{num}.py')]
    proc = Process(target=subprocess.run, args=(sh,))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

После того как я получу рендеры, я хочу их загрузить на s3 bucket, по этому я жду окончания этих процессов.

Я ожидал получить прирост скорости хотя бы в х4, так как теперь вместо одного рендера на одну минуту, будет проходить условно 5 рендеров за одну минуту. Однако в реальности 5 процессов запустились одновременно, один за другим записали результат в папку и суммарное время выполнение, составило 5 минут. В то время когда я ожидал что время выполнения сократиться хотя бы до 2.

Рендеринг проводился на AWS на сервере g3.16xlarge, с установленными и активированными драйверами GRID. В процессе рендеринга, половина GPU большую часть времени простаивала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо запускать процессы по числу кадров. Они конкурируют за ресурсы которых явно меньше чем нужно. [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) запустит несколько процессов и распределит кадры между ними:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess


def render(num):
    print('start', num)
    subprocess.run(['blender', '-b', 'file.blend', "-P", f'script_{num}.py'])
    print('stop', num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_cameras = 100
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        p.map(render, range(n_cameras))
    print('done')
```

Comment: Это не меняет ничего. Важно что процессов должно быть примерно столько сколько процессоров на компьютере. Впрочем вы можете установить размер пула вручную.

Comment: Только что сделал через Pool. Стало чуть по лучше, система меньше стала тормозить, однако особых улучшений замечено не было. Код выполняется за то же время что я и описывал ранее

Comment: Провел тесты, при использовании параллельных процессов, мы используем 24 процесса каждый из которых использует 1230MiB, GPU - Utilization равняется 100%. Однако если использовать последовательный рендеринг, мы используем всего 4 процесса, по 1230MiB, где GPU-Utilization также равняется 100%. Все это время на видеокарте доступно 64vCPU и 488 GiB памяти. Не понимаю каких ресурсов недостаточно?

Comment: GPU недостаточно. Вы используете его ресурся полностью. Ничего нельзя сделать кроме упрощения рендеринга.